# How can I find the the greatest common divisor with Euclid's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

How can I create a function **ggt[p,q]**,and find the greatest common divisor with Euclid's algorithm?p,q are integer.

Comment: May we assume that you are already familiar with `GCD[n1, n2,...]'?

Comment: I think I only knew a little about `GCD[n1, n2,...]'

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
ggt[p_, q_] := First[NestWhile[{Last[#], Mod @@ #} &, {p, q}, Last[#] != 0 &]]
```

Comment: Can I also build a  fraction e.g. b=p/q?

Comment: @JoneWill The function works correctly for rational input too