# GCD using Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: recursion, number-theory

My assignment is to calculate the GCD of two numbers n and m using the Euclidean Algorithm which basically states that if the remainder = 0 the GCD is the 2nd of the two numbers. SO my thought was to write a recursive program looking for the GCD of two numbers, if the remainder is not 0 then change n to m and m to r and then calculate the GCD of those two numbers until you get a remainder of 0.
I am not strong with recursion and my program loops forever. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
MyBetterGCD[n_, m_] :=
 Module[{q, r, DebugFlag = True},
  r = Mod[n, m]; (*remainder*)
  While[r != 0,
   q = Floor[(n/m)]; (*quotient*)
   n = m;
   m = r;
   MyBetterGCD[n, m];
   ];(*End While Loop*)
  Return[m]
  ](*End Module*)
```

Comment: Your loop never terminates because the variable `r` is never changed within the loop. You need to redeine `r` within the loop.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138160/

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking you are trying to use a loop **AND** recursion. Usually you need one of those. Also [Recursive Euclidean algorithm in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84119/recursive-euclidean-algorithm-in-mathematica) addresses this algorithm.

But you probably want to completely avoid loops since you are using *Mathematica*. Something like this should work:

```
gcd[a_, 0] := a;
gcd[a_, b_] := gcd[b, Mod[a, b]];
gcd[24, 18]
(* 6 *)
```